# Converting a text string to a Google BigQuery TableSchema

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I've been trying, and failing, to generate a Google BigQuery table using a schema that I build from text.

I have no problem defining the schema in script like this:
*var fl = {fields: [{name: 'issue_id', type: 'STRING'},.....}*
then assigning it as *schema: fl*

What I want to do is use an array as input to the field list (e.g. *name, type*) and dynamically build this list into a table schema. I can do this in text (simple string building) but I can't use a text string as a schema - it appears as a null.

There's probably a wildly simple solution but I've not found it yet. It needs to avoid any add-ons if at all possible.

**Specific code information**

This is the table definition, which requires a schema.

```
var table = {
  tableReference: {
    projectId: projectId,
    datasetId: datasetId,
    tableId: tableId
  },
  schema: fl
};
```

If I define **fl** as below, I don't have a problem. I'm using the expected syntax and it all works.

```
var fl = {fields: [{name: 'issue_id', type: 'STRING'},{name: 'internal_issue_id', type: 'STRING'}] };
```

However, if I define **fl** as below (**fs** is an array and I'm concatenating text from this array), I end up with fl as a string, which doesn't work here.

```
var fl = "{fields: ["
while (countRow<numRows) {
  fl = fieldList + "{name: '" + fs[countRow][0] + "', type: '" + fs[countRow][1] + "'},";
  countRow=countRow+1
}
fl = fl.substring(0,fl.length-1) + "] }"
```

The string looks exactly like the originally defined variable, but of course is a string so I didn't really expect it to work without some sort of conversion - just like a date string usually needs conversion to be used in date calculations. Currently it appears as a null to the table definition.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to do this, and hoping there's a simple solution.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Have you tried casting it to a JSON Object with `JSON.parse(fl)` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#work_with_json))? Also, you can use `Logger.log("Type: %s", typeof(variable));` to log the variable type.

Comment: Solved by creating an empty array `var nx = []` and for each row of data (= a field in the table) creating an empty object `var n1 = {}` and adding field name and type as parameters `n1.name=fieldstore[countRow][0]`  

These are then pushed into the array `nx.push(n1)` and the object is re-created (important) each time around.  

Finally the fieldlist is assigned `var fieldList = {fields: nx}`  

I would list the code here, but comment formatting is beyond me!

Comment: I would encourage you to post it as an answer then as it helps the community (and answers allow for better formatting)